# How to parallel process inputs until some condition is true in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, while-loop

I am working with an interface which sits on top of (for example) a `StreamReader` or `SqlDataReader`. The interface exposes a method, `GetNext()`, which returns an object if there are any left, or `null` if there are none left.

```
public interface ICollectionWidget<T>
{
    T GetNext(); // Returns a T if there are any left, or null if there aren't
}
```

I need to process each `T` returned by `GetNext()` in parallel, and stop processing when  `GetNext()` returns `null`. I'm not quite sure how this is done (using TPL or whatever). I need a kind of parallel `while`! Obviously, I don't want any threads still processing to finish when I get a `null`, I just don't want to add any new processing - and then to drop out of the 'loop' when all the threads finish what they're doing.

Can anyone help? Please let me know if my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Off the top of my head, parallel processing hits to the database via the reader `GetNext` seems like it'll be prone to failure/issues. At the very least, you might have to do your own thread locking around the `GetNext` call (which will likely put you in the same boat you're in now anyway) Do you have a real bottleneck that necessitates doing this?

Comment: Look into BackgroundWorker. You can stop them "in the middle", but your working method will have to check if they should be stopped every once in a while, because violently killing a thread isn't safe.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It seems to me that he wants parallel processing of returned T's (single threaded while loop), and the processing is what takes long, not the GetNext, and he wants to stop the GetNext and the processing of parallel T's if a single T processed satisfies a condition.

Comment: @Yorye: you're right in that it's the processing of Ts returned from `GetNext()` that I want to parallelise, but I only want to stop when `GetNext()` returns null. Even when it does, I want to allow any outstanding processing to complete.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, that makes more sense. Totally doable (see below answers)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that "collections" like the one you're showing are typically expose via `IEnumerable<T>`.  If you have control over the API itself, I'd use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of the `GetNext()`-based iteration approach.  If you don't, however, it's simple to perform the conversion...

I would wrap this API to expose it as an `IEnumerable<T>`.  You could then use `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
private IEnumerable<T> EnumerateWidgets<T>(ICollectionWidget<T> widgets)
{
    T element = widgets.GetNext();
    while (element != null)
    {
        yield return element;
        element = widgets.GetNext();
    }
}
```

You could then use:

```
Parallel.ForEach(EnumerateWidgets(widgetCollection), widget =>
{
     // Process widget here
});
```

This will prevent threading issues while enumerating your widgets (as the enumerator will be single threaded), but allow you to process your collection in parallel.

Comment: I almost physically slapped my forehead when I read this, but I have to admit I probably wouldn't have thought of it. Thanks! btw, I've come across your name a lot since I started looking at parallel processing in the past week. :)

Comment: @David I've written a lot about the TPL, including Parallel.ForEach, here: http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/

Comment: Rather than wrapping the `ICollectionWidget` with an object that implements `IEnumerable` I would just replace `ICollectionWidget` with  `IEnumerable` altogether.

Comment: @Servy -`ICollectionWidget` is my interface, and you're quite right, I need to change the API so that it implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Servy I recommend that (first paragraph), but if it's a third party API, that may not be an option.  Wasn't sure...

Answer (score 1):

Just make an iterator:

```
public interface ICollectionWidget<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetItems();
}

public class CollectionWidget : ICollectionWidget<int>
{
    public IEnumerable<int> GetItems()
    {
        var i = 0;

        while (i++ < 10)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

and use it in `Parallel`:

```
        var widget = new CollectionWidget();

        Parallel.ForEach(widget.GetItems(), i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use

```
Task.Factory.StartNew()
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more?